# Javascript how can I create an object with numbers in sequence

Tags: javascript, object, integer, sequence

I'm looking for the best way to create an object like this in javascript:

```
  values: {
    0: { 0: 0, 1: 0, …, 59: 0 },
    1: { 0: 0, 1: 0, …, 59: 0 },
    …,
    58: { 0: 0, 1: 0, …, 59: 0 },
    59: { 0: 0, 1: 0, …, 59: 0 }
  }
```

Comment: If everything is 0-based, have you considered nested arrays instead?

Comment: *I'm looking for...* - Yeah, you're probably not going to just *find* it... You pretty much have to develop it...

Comment: nested for loops or two loops. First create object, second loop, clone, and insert

Comment: Sorry, I voted the first one helped me. They are all valid answers for me. Thanks [EDIT] Yeah, probably I should vote yours for clarity

Comment: I updated my answer to use objects, not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var values = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 60; ++i) {
    values[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < 60; ++j)
        values[i][j] = 0;
}

console.log(values);
```

That what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: a functional approach:

```js
function range(n, cb) {
   cb = cb || function (v, i) { this[i] = 0; };
   var _ = {};
   Array(n).join()
    .split(',')
    .map( cb, _);
    return _;
}

// create someObj using range
var someObj = range(10, function (v, i) { this[i] = range(10); });

// display someObj
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 
   '<code>'+
   JSON.stringify(someObj)
   .split('},')
   .join('},<br>&nbsp;')  
   + '</code>';
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var values = {}, temp = {}, i;
for (i = 0; i <= 59; i++)
{
    temp[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i <= 59; i++)
{
    values[i] = temp;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwhbxubv/1/).

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
var obj = {};
var n = 60;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
 obj[i] = {}
 for(var j=0;j<n;j++)
   obj[i][j] = 0;
 }
```

obj is your values